# Extract values following specific substrings in string containing spaces using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have this single line string.

`WordPress version: 5.5.3 Database revision: 48748 TinyMCE version: 4.9100 (49100-20200624) Package language: en_US`

I would like to extract **5.5.3** and **en_US**

This is the closest example I am able to come up with where a space is the delimiter.

```
`awk -F" " '{print $3 $13 }' <<< 'WordPress version: 5.5.3 Database revision: 48748 TinyMCE version: 4.9100 (49100-20200624) Package language: en_US'`
```

which returns

`5.5.3en_US`

I have looked at other examples and I am not getting anywhere. I would prefer to not rely on any counts ($3 and $13) and take the first value after a substring. In this case, **WordPress version:** and **Package language:**

Putting these two variables into an array would be awesome. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Can we use `grep` instead of `awk`?: `echo "WordPress version: 5.5.3 Database revision: 48748 TinyMCE version: 4.9100 (49100-20200624) Package language: en_US" |grep -Po 'WordPress version:\s*\K[0-9\.]+|Package language:\s*\K\S+'`

Answer (score 0):

If `awk` is no requirement you could just cut string into substrings with `grep`,
replace colons with `=` and whitespaces with `_` with `sed`.
The output could evaluated with `eval` to make it variables

```
WordPress version: 5.5.3 -> WordPress_version=5.5.3
Database revision: 48748 -> Database_revision=48748
TinyMCE version: 4.9100  -> TinyMCE_version=4.9100
Package language: en_US  -> Package_language=en_US
```

to make this work you need to differ variable names from variable values.
in this example this is done by `len` so **en_US** is treated as value

```
#!/bin/bash

# input string
text='WordPress version: 5.5.3 Database revision: 48748 TinyMCE version: 4.9100 (49100-20200624) Package language: en_US'

# variable length
len=6

# find variable names based on length
for var in $(echo "$text" | grep -oE "[^(0-9:)]{$((len+1)),}" | grep -oE '\S.*' | sed -n 's,\s,.,p')
  do
    # convert substrings and set variables name=value
    eval "$(echo "$text" | grep -oE "$var:\s+\S+" | sed -nr 's,:\s+,=,p' | sed -n 's,\s,_,p')"
done

# print variable info
declare -p | grep -E 'declare -- [A-Za-z]+_\S+='
```

Note: `eval` is just used for demonstration. the above code is compatible with `(da)sh`. in `bash` you can create array instead of multiple variables